# stuck with the first wxPython example

Tags: wxpython

Got stuck with the first wxPython code

```
import wx
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        wx.MessageBox("Hello World" , "wxapp")
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is what i got

```
File "/home/bunny/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    class MyApp(wx.App):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'App'
```

Please help me out!

**EDIT**:
I run the same code again. Here is the error i got

```
runfile('/home/bunny/.spyder2/.temp.py', wdir='/home/bunny/.spyder2')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-7a0438cfddad>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/bunny/.spyder2/.temp.py', wdir='/home/bunny/.spyder2')

  File "/home/bunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site- packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/bunny/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    class MyApp(wx.App):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'App'
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me.  Why is the error message saying that `class MyApp(wx.App)` is on line 10, when it is on line 2 in the code?   Is there more code that you are not showing us?   Are you actually running this code, or some other code by accident?

Comment: No its the same code, I run it again and put the log in the post

Comment: maybe it is installation issue since during installation i got an error


    W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/trusty-wx/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/trusty-wx/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/trusty-wx/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found



I installed it useing the instructions from [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian)

Comment: Yes.  That would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error initially,but then i recompiled the source code and it worked fine.

From the source code,type:

```
./configure
```

Then

```
make
```

and finally

```
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ... Finally solved it.

I thought it would be helpful for others, so I am answering to my own question

I was using Anaconda. On importing wx on anaconda console I found that libSDL.-1.2.so was missing

1)First I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian
```

2)Then I got another error in anaconda something like 
    version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0)

3)Then I looked [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/rX_c12a7Sps) and renamed anaconda/lib/libm.so.6 file and boom , wxPython started running on anaconda

This solved the issue..

Comment: what did you rename libm.so.6 to ?